# How do I setup ReSharper with Stylecop 4.5?

Tags: c#, resharper, stylecop, resharper-plugins

I just installed Stylecop 4.5 RC.  I also installed ReSharper 5.1.  However, I don't see StyleCop in the Tools section of ReSharper.  Is ReShaper supposed to be able to get my code up to stuff with StyleCop's recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StyleCop on CodePlex](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/)

The version 4.5 and upwards would have the R# plugin check out the release page [here](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/62209)

Excerpt from 4.5RC Release Notes

> This is the StyleCop 4.5 RC4.
>
> The version number is 4.5.16.0.
>
> This release includes the very latest
>   StyleCop for ReSharper plugin and will
>   automatically uninstall previous
>   versions of StyleCop.

Comment: Ok, I just installed StyleCop 4.5 RC.

Comment: I installed it but I still don't see the ReSharper plugin, do I have to do something else to install it?

Comment: I don't see it in Tools plugin after install.

Comment: Have you checked under ReSharper-> Plugins.. ?

Comment: I don't see it in there.  Do you have it in there?  It does kind of look like it is working (underlines functions I have that start with lowercase - but that doesn't seem to be Stylecop's doing...)

Comment: For anyone like me stumbling across this when trying to setup ReSharper 9 and Stylecop 4.7 - You have to separately install "ReSharper.StyleCop (for R# 9)" via Resharper -> Extension Manager.

Answer (score 3):

Did you install Resharper first? You need Resharper 5.1 installed, then when you install StyleCop 4.5 you'll see the plugin in the list of things to install.